# Flask application and mysql database: NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql-python

So I have tried to install all necessary libraries into my application, I have also checked similar problems online but I keep getting this error when I run my application when I remove the imports it runs. what can I do? here is the error below:

```
File "/Usssd/scsx/Documents/axd_admin_dashboard/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Usss/maxsd/Documents/xsd_admin_dashboard/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_mysql_affected_rows'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maxds/Documents/xsd_admin_dashboard/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
  File "/U
ss/maxds/Documents/xsd_admin_dashboard/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/Uss/maxds/Documents/xsd_admin_dashboard/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

Comment: do you have installed server MySQL? [Download MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

Comment: on MySQL page you can also find Python module to work with MySQL database - and sometimes it can be better than other modules - [Download connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)